# Invert the color of a UIView and all its subviews

Tags: ios, uiview

Is it possible to invert the color of a UIView or UIScrollView and all its subviews in iOS?

If so how can I accomplish this?

Comment: Isn't this basically a repeat of [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24835874/inverting-the-colors-of-a-uiscrollview)?

Answer (score -1):

First, you need to create an inverted color of current background color of `UIView`. You can learn more about how to accomplish it on this StackOverflow question — [How to get inverse color from UIColor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893261/how-to-get-inverse-color-from-uicolor)

Then, you need to iterate over all UIView subviews and apply inverted color as a background.

```
view.backgroundColor = invertedColor;
for (UIView *subview in view.subviews) {
    subview.backgroundColor = invertedColor;
}
```

Comment: What if the UIView contains a PDF? and not just a background color?