# How to get a color opposite to primary color?

Tags: swift, swiftui

SwiftUI offers theme dependent `Color`s like `.primary` and `.secondary`. How to get inverted versions of these (to use as background for example)? System itself knows which background color to use depending on light/dark theme.

Comment: The system does it by calling this method: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/3238042-resolvedcolor So can you.

Comment: You can create `UIColor` with needed `Color` then invert it (using approach like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/5901586/12299030) then convert back by creating `Color` with result `UIColor`.

Comment: The proper way to invert a color in SwiftUI is to call `.colorInvert()` on the color. It takes the current color, adjusted for dark mode, etc, and returns its inverse.

Comment: `.colorInvert()` produces `some View` and cannot be used where `Color` parameter is expected, @Yrb. Though it is possible for example to use it on a `Text` to invert its color of course.

Comment: You had asked specifically about using as a background which takes a view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the colors "label" and "systembackground", they are usually opposite.

So use UIColor.systemBackground and UIColor.systemLabel for the opposite

or UIColor.secondarySystemBackground and UIColor.secondarySystemLabel etc...

Comment: @Paul B Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: I was looking for SwiftUI way of doing this, not UIKit way. But since we can do `Color(uiColor: UIColor.systemBackground)` in iOS 15 to get the `Color` bridged to `UIColor` the suggested solution is a working one, @Abv. There are plenty of theme dependent colors in UIColor.

Comment: Type 'UIColor' has no member 'systemLabel'