# How to change Text color based on background Image - Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, textcolor

I want to change text (and Icon) colors based on the background image for visibility.

**I've tried:** 
Using [palette_generator](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/palette_generator) package, to check the Dominant Color of the background Image and *useWhiteForgroundForColor*  function (returns a bool) from [flutter_statusbarcolor](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_statusbarcolor) package to select black or white color for the my text (and Icon) colors.

**The Problem:** Sometimes dominant color turns out null. In my tests, this happens with black and white colors and I don't know of any ways to find out which one.

```
Future<bool> useWhiteTextColor(String imageUrl) async {
  PaletteGenerator paletteGenerator =
      await PaletteGenerator.fromImageProvider(
    NetworkImage(imageUrl),

    // Images are square
    size: Size(300, 300),

    // I want the dominant color of the top left section of the image
    region: Offset.zero & Size(40, 40),
  );

  Color dominantColor = paletteGenerator.dominantColor?.color;

  // Here's the problem 
  // Sometimes dominantColor returns null
  // With black and white background colors in my tests
  if (dominantColor == null) print('Dominant Color null');

  return useWhiteForeground(dominantColor);
}
```

I found [other methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19456288/text-color-based-on-background-image) for other languages, but I don't know a way to implement the same method in dart.

Additional note:
My actual code includes some additional complications. I am using a SliverAppBar and here I want to determine the title and icons colors for when the flexibleSpace is expanded. I change their colors when collapsed with the help of the community based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53372276/flutter-how-to-check-if-sliver-appbar-is-expanded-or-collapsed).

Answer (score 50):

the color class already has a method to calculate luminance, called ***computeLuminance()***

```
Color textColor = color.computeLuminance() > 0.5 ? Colors.black : Colors.white;
```

Comment: as mentioned above, sometimes the color returns null.
so I can't use this method on it

Comment: Warning: As per the computeLuminance(...) docs `This value is computationally expensive to calculate.`

Answer (score 9):

I use the method below to find out which one should be used (either black or white):

```
Color getTextColor(Color color) {
  int d = 0;

  // Counting the perceptive luminance - human eye favors green color...
  double luminance =
      (0.299 * color.red + 0.587 * color.green + 0.114 * color.blue) / 255;

  if (luminance > 0.5)
    d = 0; // bright colors - black font
  else
    d = 255; // dark colors - white font

  return Color.fromARGB(color.alpha, d, d, d);
}
```

Comment: my problem is mostly for getting the color of the background image. 
if it returns null, I can't use this method for it

Comment: This doesn't seem computationally expensive like computeLuminance()

Answer (score 6):

There are Two ways of getting Text Color based upon the BG Color of Card or Button or Tags.

First One is :

```
Color txColor = color.computeLuminance() < 0.5 ? Colors.white : Colors.black;
```

The Second is using Theme , Where user may have dark theme or light theme of device.

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ColorEstimationPage extends StatelessWidget {
  Color _randomBackgroundColor() {
    List<Color> colors = [Colors.red, Colors.green, Colors.amber, Colors.black];

    return colors[Random().nextInt(colors.length)];
  }
   /// With this you can get the Color either black or white
  Color _textColorForBackground(Color backgroundColor) {
    if (ThemeData.estimateBrightnessForColor(backgroundColor) ==
        Brightness.dark) {
      return Colors.white;
    }

    return Colors.black;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Color bgColor = _randomBackgroundColor();
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: bgColor,
      body: Center(
        child: Text(
          "I'm the correct text color!",
          style: TextStyle(color: _textColorForBackground(bgColor)),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should create the palette generator like this

```
PaletteGenerator paletteGenerator =
  await PaletteGenerator.fromImageProvider(
NetworkImage(imageUrl),

filters: [],
// Images are square
size: Size(300, 300),

// I want the dominant color of the top left section of the image
region: Offset.zero & Size(40, 40),
);
```

notice the empty list in the filters parameter

Answer (score 2):

**Colorful colors**

If you have font/background colors that aren't only black and white, you should use some thing else:

```dart
 final colorDifference = newBackgroundColor.computeLuminance() -
        textColor.computeLuminance();
    if (colorDifference.abs() < 0.2) {
      textColor = textColor.computeLuminance() > 0.5
          ? Colors.black
          : Colors.white;
    }
```

With this, you **will only change the font color if necessary** (the luminance difference is so less that the colors don't really stand out).

Answer (score 1):

Not quite what you were looking for, but I noticed that the CircleAvatar does this with background colors, so I checked out the code for that widget and it came up with ThemeData.estimateBrightnessForColor().
Since computeLuminance didn't quite work for me, I implemented the following:

```
 _lightOrDarkColor(bgColor) {
switch (ThemeData.estimateBrightnessForColor(bgColor!)) {
  case Brightness.dark:
    return Colors.white;
  case Brightness.light:
    return Colors.black;
}
```

}

Maybe it helps someone.

Comment: Beautiful observation, thank you

Answer (score -1):

For buttons you can use. this will auto change button color based on background

```
buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(
   buttonColor: Colors.teal[500],
   textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.primary
)
```