# Watch below widget color and update the above widget colors

Tags: flutter

I had found the solution and proposed it to Flutter, here is the [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/139411).

---

In flutter, how can I make a button that can change color according to it’s below widget?

Here’s the example, see the button on the top right of the video.

[image]

> Video link is here: https://imgur.com/9aJWy30
> If browser didn't render

Flutter has [some functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68065724) help get the inverse color but I can’t find the widget or package to help me watch the color and notify its ascendant widget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might not be exactly like the one in the video, but you can achieve similar results by using `BlendMode.difference`:

```dart
Container(
  width: 50,
  height: 50,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.white,
    backgroundBlendMode: BlendMode.difference,
  ),
  child: SizedBox(),
),
```

Video: https://imgur.com/a/NGW9MWI

Comment: This is a great solution and I will accept this answer if there are no other answers after a week!