# How to calculate the correct Text Color for status bar programmatically?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, statusbar

I'm developing an iOS app where's the app's main color (and the status bar color too) can be chosen by user. Is there any function to calculate if It's better a white or black text color on status bar programmaticaly starting from a RGB or HEX color?

Comment: So, you essentially want us to write the main function of your app for you? There's nothing wrong with asking a question like this, but please provide code snippets showing us your attempts next time.

Comment: I'm not asking it. @rmaddy asked perfectly my question.

Comment: My apologies - the wording of the your question may have confused me then. Glad you got your answer! Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I do. In summary - get the RGB values for the color. Then calculate a grayscale value from the RGB values. Then choose the status bar style based on the grayscale.

Step 1 - get the RGB values from a `UIColor`:

```
UIColor *color =  // your color
CGFloat red, green, blue, alpha;

if (![color getRed:&red green:&green blue:&blue alpha:&alpha]) {

    CGFloat white;
    if ([color getWhite:&white alpha:&alpha]) {
        red = green = blue = white;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Uh oh, not RGB or grayscale");
    }
}
```

Step 2 - calculate a gray value from the RGB values:

```
CGFloat gray = 0.299 * red + 0.587 * green + 0.114 * blue;
```

Step 3 - choose the status bar style:

```
UIStatusBarStyle style = gray > 0.6 ? UIStatusBarStyleDefault : UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
```

The use of `0.6` generally works. You may want to adjust that to suit your tastes.

Comment: Wow man, thanks! Can I ask why exactly 0.299, 0.587 and 0.114 as moltiplicator?

Comment: That's a standard formula to convert RGB values to grayscale. I didn't make it up.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link
[Check if UIColor is dark or bright?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509443/check-if-uicolor-is-dark-or-bright)

And you can find out your RGB values with something like;

```
const CGFloat *colors = CGColorGetComponents(self.view.backgroundColor.CGColor );

NSLog(@"R:%f G:%f B:%f",colors[0],colors[1],colors[2]);
```

Then calculate your desired text colour based on these.