# Is it possible for cgColor.convert to give components less than 3? (when converting to RGB)

Tags: swift, uikit, uicolor

Upon reading [a SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509443/check-if-uicolor-is-dark-or-bright) about checking whether a color is bright, I found this piece of code by @josh-fuggle:

```swift
extension UIColor {

    // Check if the color is light or dark, as defined by the injected lightness threshold.
    // Some people report that 0.7 is best. I suggest to find out for yourself.
    // A nil value is returned if the lightness couldn't be determined.
    func isLight(threshold: Float = 0.5) -> Bool? {
        let originalCGColor = self.cgColor

        // Now we need to convert it to the RGB colorspace. UIColor.white / UIColor.black are greyscale and not RGB.
        // If you don't do this then you will crash when accessing components index 2 below when evaluating greyscale colors.
        let RGBCGColor = originalCGColor.converted(to: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), intent: .defaultIntent, options: nil)
        guard let components = RGBCGColor?.components else {
            return nil
        }
        guard components.count >= 3 else {
            return nil
        }

        let brightness = Float(((components[0] * 299) + (components[1] * 587) + (components[2] * 114)) / 1000)
        return (brightness > threshold)
    }
}
```

In the code, the `guard` statements ensure that the converted color is not `nil`, and has three or more components.

So my question is, is there any color that makes the whole `isLight` function return `nil`?

Comment: `RGBCGColor` should be called `rgbCGColor`. I just spent like 2 minutes trying to find a class called `RGBCGColor` lol

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1455930-cgcolorgetcomponents?language=objc "The size of the array is one more than the number of components of the color space for the color." Might be different  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgcolorspace/color_space_names, but since you are doing `CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB`, you should get 4 (Red,Green,Bluee & alpha).

Comment: You should use UIColor method getWhite as shown in the same question https://stackoverflow.com/a/40062565/2303865